# How to prevent modifiers from transferring onto separated faces?

Tags: modeling

When you separate faces into an object of its own, it inherits the modifiers. How do I just detach my faces without those modifiers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Erase them after the fact, I don't know of any method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, this is how the separate operation works.

The preinstalled *Modifier Tools* add-on may make handling modifier stacks easier.

[image]

Comment: You can select many objects and Alt+Click on "delete all" (except if "emulate 3 buttons mouse" is selected in the user preferences)

Answer (score 0):

Try separating **first** and apply a modifier to the other faces. Later you may combine them with **CTRL+J**